# How can I check if Upgrade Pack is installed in the Lotus Notes client?

Tags: windows, installation, lotus-notes, lotus

Lotus Notes client 8.53 with FPx and Upgrade Pack 1 are installed to clients using a package management solution.

I need to check that it works and actually get the Upgrade Pack installed.

The Fix Pack install removes the listing for Upgrade Pack in the Control Panel / Program, if we install Upgrade Pack last the Fix Pack listing is removed.

Doesn't sound quite right(?).

Thanks!

/J

Comment: Technically, this isn't a programming question so it should have been asked on ServerFault instead of StackOverflow.  But I'm glad you got your answers.

Comment: @RichardSchwartz For me, I'd like it to be a programming question - that is, I'd like to be able to determine programmatically that the client hasn't upgraded and either report that to the Help Desk or give the user a pop-up to let them know they need to perform or request the upgrade.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ExtLib installation can be checked easily from menu:

*Help -> About IBM Lotus Notes -> Feature Details*

For me the extlib features there are:

[image]

For upgrade pack I believe you should see the same with 2011 dates except for the last "extlibx" (experimental) line which does not come with Upgrade Pack.

Simon added his answer while I was writing this but looks like he mentions "Plugin detail", not "Feature Details" so I'll post this answer too.

Answer (score 2):

A couple of ways.

1. Click on the "About -> Lotus Notes" in the menu, select "Plugin details" and check if it exists there.
2. Check for the related folders in the features/plugins folder.
3. Have the user open an application which renders an extlib component. If it reports a problem then it didn't install correctly.
4. Launch notes with the OSGi console. Create a short cut like.

   C:\Lotus\Notes\notes.exe -RPARAMS -console -debug -separateSysLogFiles -consoleLog

then type SS [package name] to get the output of installed components.

Comment: There are many ways to skin a cat ;-) Very cool, didn't know about option 4 ;-) +1

Answer (score 1):

To check for upgrade pack, check the follwoing locations in your designer or notes install:

- framework\shared\eclipse\features and framework\shared\eclipse\plugins
- data\domino\workspace\applications\eclipse\features and data\domino\workspace\applications\eclipse\plugins
- data\workspace\applications\eclipse\features and data\workspace\applications\eclipse\plugins

Check for files with that contain domino.das, domino.services, wink, or extlib in their names.

Source: 
http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/ddwiki.nsf/xpDocViewer.xsp?lookupName=Domino+Designer+XPages+Extension+Library#action=openDocument&res_title=Installing_the_upgrade_pack_on_Domino_Designer_and_Notes_ddxl853&content=pdcontent